# Does Just Cause 3 use hitscan or bullet projectiles?

Tags: just-cause-3

It's difficult to tell in game because most engagements are at close range. If the game uses both kinds of weapons, which ones are projectile based?

Edit: Enemy sniper bullets appear to be projectile based as Rico appears to take damage when the "bullet" hits him and not the same frame the trigger is pulled, but I cannot say this definitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All bullets are handled as hitscan when the target is within a certain distance (this depends on each weapon). At longer distances, some weapons become pseudo-projectiles, in order to mimic bullet travel time. The only time this is evident is when using sniper rifles, or being fired upon by a sniper or mounted machine gun that is far away.